# Link bug when submitting a comment for an answer

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

Your shorten-routine for links has a small bug in it.

Because this url has an ' in it, you cut it short:

http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx

You cut it where the ' starts.

Comment: [http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx](http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In this case you need to format the link in this format: `[]()`

For e.g. write the following in the comment:

`[http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx](http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx)`

It will show you like this:

[http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx](http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void%E2%80%99s.aspx)

Comment: [http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx](http://danielfrost.dk/post/2013/04/15/Remember-to-think-a-bit-extra-when-using-async-void’s.aspx)

Comment: Also, why not dress up the link while you're at it? Naked URLs are ugly.